Create React App Error: ERESOLVE error dependency
I was creating my first React app using this command mentioned on react.dev website:
npx create-react-app my-app

and it is throwing error:
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
PS D:\Project\React Course> npx uninstall react react-dom

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\tanma\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-12-25T08_07_29_799Z-debug-0.log


Node version - 22.12.0
npm version - 10.9.0


This question is similar to: Error in creating new react app using create-react-app appname. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And I'm pretty sure CRA is mentioned nowhere on react.dev, as it's been unsupported for a whole.

Same erorr
Try to do it with vite
npm create vite@latest

